# twig/wordpress check if value is in array

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I am testing if a value exists in an array in my twig template

```html
<input type="hidden" name="s" value="{{ search_value }}">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"  
           name="cat[]" 
           value="3" 
           onchange="this.form.submit()"
           {% if 3 in cat  ? ' checked' : '' %} >
    <span>cbd</span>
  </label>
  {{ cat }}
```

My `{{ cat }}` dumps array on the page, I'm sure my problem is a silly syntax error. The error i get is

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Unexpected end of template.
in....

if I wrap in this way I get a different error

```
 {% (if 3 in cat)  ? ' checked' : '' %} >
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: A block must start with a tag name.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a proper [if](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/if.html):

```
{% if 3 in cat %}checked{% endif %}
```

Or a [ternary](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html) (search for "The ternary operator"):

```
{{ 3 in cat ? ' checked' : '' }}
```

Or a shortened ternary:

```
{{ 3 in cat ? ' checked' }}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding. Currently I have this (it is also what i started with)        {{ (3 in cat) ? ' checked' : '' }}  it doesn't work :(   I tried all 3 with no luck. It is Wordpress, it is a filtering system for the search.. my URL is t/search-results/?s=cannabis&cat[]=3   it is filtering with cat[]=3 and if I dump {{cat }} it says 'array'  on page

Comment: actually, it works, I had a merge conflict and some code got overwritten.. thank you